# Почему LinearLayout не выделяет для каждого представле­ния ровно 50 % своей ширины?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

Всем привет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в Android Studio LinearLayout не выделяет для каждого представле­ния ровно 50 % своей ширины?

**Пример:**

[image]

У каждой кнопки `android:layout_weight` равен **1**, однако, в области предварительного просмотра первая кнопка явно занимает больше пространства.

*В **Eclipse** работает нормально!!!*

Comment: попробуйте поставить `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: А еще weight_sum у леяута = 1, если мне не кажется.

Comment: @metalurgus да, у главного LinearLayout свойство weight_sum равно 1, это не правильно?

Comment: @Barmaley вот [здесь][1] об этом тоже упоминали, но не помогло, как только не пробовал.

[1]: http://www.android-ru.info/kak-rabotaet-android-layout-weight/

Comment: @metalurgus правильно заметил! Свойство weight_sum надо удалить из главного LinearLayout. Спасибо! Сделайте ответом, пожалуйста, я поставлю плюс!

Comment: @Артёмыч, у них тут у всех и так плюсиков много))) Мне ставьте)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вам просто лайк ) @metalurgus, хотелось бы его поощрить, если, конечно, человек сам пожелает )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просуммирую [@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley) & [@metalurgus](/users/3997/metalurgus):

1) **weight_sum** вам не нужен.

2) в обеих кнопках надо ширину обнулить:

> android:layout_width="0dp"

Comment: Да, спасибо ) Разобрался.

Comment: Хотя, если у кнопок свойство layout_width равно wrap_content, то ширина кнопок тоже распределяется поровну, почему обязательно надо выставлять 0dp, это какая особенность, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Если у обеих кнопок задать ширину match_parent тоже сработает

Comment: @Артёмыч, ИМХО, лучше таки 0 ставить. Ибо элементы будут расширяться или по весу или по указанным конкретным DP. В итоге читаемость кода, по мне, улучшается.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я вас понял, спасибо! Закрываю вопрос.

Comment: @Артёмыч
> Хотя, если у кнопок свойство layout_width равно wrap_content, то ширина кнопок тоже распределяется поровну, почему обязательно надо выставлять 0dp, это какая особенность, подскажите пожалуйста?

Это только до тех пор, пока у кнопок текст одинаковой длинны. Попробуйте поставить разной длинны, и вы увидите разницу.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

Убрать или поставить  = "2" - и все будет ок.